# How do I change the number of products in the grid on different pages in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

Here is my issue. Through out my shop, the design is to have a 3 column grid displaying products with multiple rows. However, on the Home Page I want it to only show 4 column grid on one row. How do I go about doing that? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

The grid outputs

```
<ul> <li>
```

type output, so it should just be a matter of overridding the css on the page.  Probably if you put a div wrapper around the block on the homepage and override the css that controls the grid you'll be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You may find the solution at the layout xml.

Turn to "design/frontend/base/default/layout/catalog.xml" to find "`<catalog_category_default>`" tag. Several sub-tags which defined the grid column number could be found as below:

```
<action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
<action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
<action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>4</count></action>
<action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>4</count></action>
<action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>3</count></action>
```

For instance, the last line means when the layout of "Catalog Category" page is 3-columns, the grid would show 3 products in a row.